# ReactJS make-react-app imported image for CSS background doesn't work when in conditional

Tags: reactjs

Images located within /src folder are not handled properly when used as conditional value for CSS background-image property. On both "npm start" server and static build, all that gets returned for background-image value is image file name, no path is added in front and image doesn't get copied to static folders nor encoded as base64.

This won't work:

```
import imageNone from '../img/UI/select_none.png';
...
const imageStyle= { backgroundImage:'url('+( props.option.image === '' ? imageNone : props.option.image )+')'}
```

This won't work either:

```
if( props.option.image )
        imageStyle['backgroundImage'] = 'url('+props.option.image+')';
    else
        imageStyle['backgroundImage'] = 'url('+imageNone+')';
```

Using require('../img/UI/select_none.png') instead of the imported imageNone makes no difference, I get only image file name and it doesn't get processed.

This works (because no conditional, but not what I need), image gets base64 encoded:

```
import imageNone from '../img/UI/select_none.png';
...
const imageStyle= { backgroundImage:'url('+imageNone+')' }
```

Just curious if this is a bug or am I supposed to handle this in a different way.

WSL2, app made with create-react-app

```
"react": "^17.0.2",
"react-dom": "^17.0.2",
"react-scripts": "4.0.3",
"web-vitals": "^1.1.1"
```